# listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3657

Tags: node.js, electron, discord.js

I've just started developing in node.js and I don't fully understand the concept of ports and localhost debugging yet, when I was trying to make a program (discord bot using discord.js) with electron I gave me this error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3657. I am using Windows 10 operating system and I don't really understand why the port isn't listening because when I look at the port using netstat -ab it is listed as "LISTENING", any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error code `EADDRINUSE` means that the port you're trying to use in your application (3657) is actually used by another application. We cannot run 2 different applications on the same port on the machine. You can find what application running on port 3657, then stop this application and start yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it, I was actually using the port for Spotify, thanks for the help!